# Properties of Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm having some trouble understanding how to approach this problem.  Any help is appreciated.

Suppose **$\alpha$** is an archlength- parameterized space curve with the property that $\left\|\alpha(s)\right\| \le \left\|\alpha(s_0)\right\|=R$ for all $s$ sufficiently close to $s_0$.  Prove that $\kappa(s_0) \ge \left(\frac{1}{R}\right)$.

*Hint*: Consider the function $f(s) = \left\|\alpha(s)\right\|^2.$  What do we know about $f''(s_0)$?

Answer (score 0):

$||\alpha(s)||$ attains maximum at the point $s_0$ thus $f''(s_0) < 0$. So $\left<\alpha', \alpha '\right> + \left<\alpha, \alpha ''\right> < 0$. By Frenet you get $0> \left<\alpha', \alpha '\right> + \left<\alpha, \alpha ''\right> =1+k\left<\alpha, n\right> >1- kR$. Q.E.D.

Comment: where did the  ⟨α′,α′⟩+⟨α,α′′⟩<0 come from exactly? it seems extremely random.  i must not be seeing it.

Comment: $f(s)=\left< \alpha, \alpha \right>$. differentiate twice and divide by two...

Comment: oh duh. okay this makes perfect sense now. thank you so much!